# Search for same substrings inside php array of strings

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a generated array of strings for example:

```
$array = [
  0 => 'Uk.London',
  1 => 'Uk.Manchester',
  2 => 'Uk.Liverpool',
  3 => 'Uk.Cardiff',
]
```

or for example:

```
$array = [
  0 => "[Text]/ab",
  1 => "[Text]/cd",
  2 => "[Text]/ef",
  3 => "[Text]/gh",
  4 => "[Text]/il",
]
```

I would like to search inside this array if there are similar substrings.
So in the first case should return `Uk.` and in the second case should return `[Text]/`.

Can someone help me please.
Thanks in advance.

---

**1. Edit**

Here there is my code:

```
$array = [
  0 => 'Uk.London',
  1 => 'Uk.Manchester',
  2 => 'Uk.Liverpool',
  3 => 'Uk.Cardiff',
];

$words = Array();

foreach($array as $str)
$words = array_merge($words, explode(" ", $str));

$index = Array();


foreach($words as $word)
        (isset($index[$word]))? $index[$word]++ : $index[$word] = 1;

arsort($index);

return(key($index));
```

But is returning in this case `Uk.London`

---

**2. Idea**

I was thinking about converting the array in string and then searching for duplicate substrings but I will get something like this:

`$words = 'Uk.London Uk.Manchester Uk.Liverpool Uk.Cardiff'`

And I can find the `Uk.` but I can't check if every item has the same substring.

Comment: Let us know your approach.

Comment: It is possible by multiple ways, Whats your code

Comment: Are you want to search in array of string, OR want to remove `Uk.`, `[Text]/` these from your array of string

Comment: @RanaGhosh I would like to search inside the array of strings if there are similar substrings. If there are, like in these cases, delete them.

Comment: You mean exact value?

Comment: @JeffreyHitosis yes sorry

Comment: And you want to remove the duplicate so it will just be a unique value in an array?

Comment: @JeffreyHitosis yes, exactly. First find the duplicate substrings in the array and then removes them.

Comment: @PrashantGPatil I edited with the code. Thanks

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu I edited with the code. Thanks

Comment: But your array element will like $arr = array("fat","bat","rat","cat"); Do you want to remove the 'at' & want the array("f","b","r","c")

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu well, first of all I want to find that have in commons `at`

Comment: Yes, as per my example all contains "at", so your requirements is to return `array("f","b","r","c")` right?

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu yes, exactly